# Extract data from string by perl

Tags: regex, perl

There is string "-test aaaa -machine bbb -from ccc" 
How to extract "aaaa", "bbb", "ccc" using regular?
Even string is "-from   ccc   -test    aaaa    -machine  bbb"
(Different order, several space....)

I had tried some code, but always got invalid data.

```
$str = "-test aaaa     -machine  bbb  -from ccc";
$str =~ /-test\s*(.*)\s*/;
```

print

```
aaaa   -machine  bbb  -from ccc
```

I also want to handle the below case

```
-test aa_aa -machine aab-baa-aba -from ccc
```

Comment: This will work for your test data:
`perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $str = "-test aaaa -machine bbb -from ccc"; while ($str =~ m/ (\w+)/g) { print $1."\n"; }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @matches;
my $regex = qr/-\w+\s+([\w-]+)/;

my $string = q{-test aaaa -machine bbb -from ccc};
@matches = $string =~ /$regex/g;
print "Matches for first string are: @matches\n";

my $other_string = q{-from   ccc   -test    aaaa    -machine bbb};
@matches = $other_string =~ /$regex/g;
print "Matches for second string are: @matches\n";

my $third_string = q{-test aa_aa -machine aab-baa-aba -from ccc};
@matches = $third_string =~ /$regex/g;

print "Matches for third string are: @matches";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...But if some symbol in data like "-test aa_aa -machine aab-baa-aba -from ccc". How to get data correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to use a regex, you can use a hash for that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = '-test aaaa   -machine  bbb  -from ccc';
my %field = split ' ', $str;
print Dumper(\%field);
```

The output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '-from' => 'ccc',
          '-machine' => 'bbb',
          '-test' => 'aaaa'
        };
```

No matter what the order is, the `split` returns an array of pairs (in the shape `[word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6]` and `word1`, `word3`, `word5` will be `-field_name`) that when assigned to a hash, creates it in the way that now, if you want to get the string after `-test` for example, you just access it by typing `$field{"-test"}` and do whatever you want with it.

**EDIT:** It doesn't even matter how many spaces you have in between the words or what characters are in the words. It works the same way for all cases as long as you keep it in the format `-some_field something -another_field another_thing ...`

Comment: Thank you. I had never think about "split". It's a good choice =)

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to answer the question that (I think) underlies your question - not the question that you asked.

It looks to me like you are parsing command-line options. So use a command-line option parser, rather than reinventing that for yourself. [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) is part of the standard Perl distribution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
# We use modern Perl (here, specifically, say())
use 5.010;

use Getopt::Long 'GetOptionsFromString';
use Data::Dumper;

my %options;

my $str = '-test aa_aa -machine aab-baa-aba -from ccc';
GetOptionsFromString($str, \%options, 'test=s', 'machine=s', 'from=s');

say Dumper \%options;
```

Normally, you'd use the function `GetOptions()` as you're parsing the command-line options that are available in `@ARGV`. I'm not sure how the options ended up in your string, but there's a useful `GetOptionsFromString()` function for this situation.

**Update:** To explain why your code didn't work.

```
$str = "-test aa_aa     -machine  aab-baa-aba  -from ccc";
$str =~ /-test\s*(.*)\s*/;
```

You're capturing what matches `(.*)`. But `.*` is greedy. That is, it matches as much data as it can. And, in this case, that means it matches until the end of the line. There are (at least!) a couple of ways to fix this.

1/ Make the match non-greedy by adding `?`.

```
$str =~ /-test\s*(.*?)\s*/;
```

2/ Be more explicit about what you're looking for - in this case non-whitespace characters.

```
$str =~ /-test\s*(\S*)\s*/;
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick

```
$str = "-test aa_aa     -machine  aab-baa-aba  -from ccc";
($test,$machine,$from) = $str =~ /\-test(.+)\-machine(.+)\-from(.+)/;

print "Test: $test, Machine: $machine, From: $from";
```

Comment: The order of `-test`, `-machine` and `-form` in the string can change (as explain in the question), in which case your solution won't work. Moreover, you are capturing the white-spaces as well with your `.+`, which isn't ideal. And if an additional parameter were to be added, it will be captured as the value of one of the previous parameter. Also, there is no need to escape `-` in a regex (except sometimes inside `[...]`.